# Explain the source of overfitting in choosing an additional parameter

Tags: time-series, overfitting, fitting, trend, covid-19

I was going through this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/ev42ot/oc_timelapse_and_prediction_of_wuhan_coronavirus/). It describes the '**timelapse and prediction of Wuhan coronavirus infections in Mainland China**'. The guy chose to use $y=a+b*(exp(c*x)-1)$ to describe the phenomenon. T0 which, a redditor has posted

> A bit technical, but you should be using a straight exponential without the -1 bit. The new infections depends on the number of people already infected. That's why you have exponential growth to begin with. Having a separate a from b is over fitting

I do not fully understand that comment or even the need to have a $-1$ in $y=a+b*(exp(c*x)-1)$. It is equivalent to the equation without $-1$ as far as i can see since we are now representing $a$ with $a-b$. Can you please help me understand :

1. What difference does '$-1$' cause
2. The comment stating that having a '$-1$' is overfitting

Comment: In this case, the parameter "a" should be the initial number of known infections when data collection starts, so that parameter is required.